# Using a variable at once or passing it around

Tags: python, performance

This question isn't really about Python but about Python in particular. Say, I've read a file:

```
f = open(file_name, "rb")
body = f.read()
f.close()
```

Since the file is already read in the variable and closed, does it matter in terms of **performance**  whether I use the variable `body` within the same method or pass around to another method? Is there enough information to answer my question?

Comment: `body` is *just a reference to a value*. Calling other functions incurs a cost (stack push, pop) but passing around a reference has next to 0 cost. Why are you worried about that vs. reading the whole file in one go vs. processing line by line, for example?

Comment: @MartijnPieters because it gives me agita!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't create copies of objects passed to functions (including strings)

```
def getidof(s):
    return id(s)

s = 'blabla'
id(s) == getidof(s)  # True
```

So even passing a huge string doesn't affect performances, of course you will have a slight overhead because you called a function, but the type of the argument and its length doesn't matter.